# Stop href link after onClick function is called

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a link:

```
<h2><a href=?p=article&aid='.$article->id.'" onclick="loadPage('article'); return false;">.$article->title.</a></h2>
```

and it calls this function:

```
function loadPage(page){
    $("#content").html("Loading...");

    $.post("page.php", {p: page}, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);   
    });
}
```

But after my javascript has been ran the href is still active.
I've used return false; on my onClick's before to prevent this but it's not working this time????

Comment: Please check and update your first code snippet (just copy paste what you have in reality), as there is no way this one could be doing anything at all

Comment: What kind of processing do you do inside athesyn.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your script has an error and is not reaching the return block.  If you add the try catch, it will ignore the errors in the script.

```
function loadPage(page){
try{
    $("#content").html("Loading...");

    $.post("page.php", {p: page}, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);   
    });
} catch(err){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using jQuery to bind the click event to your function, as the logic is better separated.

```
$('h2 a').click(function(event) {
    $("#content").html("Loading...");

    $.post("page.php", {p: page}, function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);   
    });

    return false;
});
```

Usually, if the `href` is still active is it likely that there was a JavaScript error.

**Edit:** You could also use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the `href` being followed with the click function bound in this way.

Lastly, the `href` does seem very well formed (missing an opening quote). Is that a typo?

Comment: I agree, just instead of `return false;` a `e.preventDefault();` (where `e` is the event argument passed to click handler) would be more appropriate ([event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/))

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this is to replace the href attribute. This has the advantage of preserving compatibility with non-JS clients, and not having to deal with 'stopping' the event or any such wizardry. For example:

```
function unobtrusiveLinkSetup(link) {
    // replace the about link's href
    J(link).attr('jshref', J(link).attr('href'));
    J(link).removeAttr('href');

    // handle the link's action
    J(link).click(function(index) {
            J(this).stop();
            // make a request in the background
            J.get(J(this).attr('jshref'), function(result) {
                // whatever you need to do with the link..
            });
    });
}
```

Then you can just do `unobtrusiveLinkSetup("#myLink");` in your document's ready function, or wherever else.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I was removing the onclick event from my link, but left the href event to fire.  Thanks!